# How to keep props in a child component inside a Flatlist?

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I'm currently using React-Native Flatlist with a custom component to show data.
The custom component show a card an should show a modal (RBSheet to be exact) on click.

The problem is that props doesn't look to be keept, when I press on a card, I get the props data from another card.

I thought about to get the clicked element on the parent, but I was not able to do through the flatlist to show the modal with the correct data.

I was not able to bind the card to get the data from its props.

My Custom Component (Entry.js)

```
return (
    <View
      style={{
        flexDirection: "row",
        alignContent: "center",
        alignItems: "center",
        textAlign: "center",
        marginBottom: "5%"
      }}
    >
      <View style={{ flexDirection: "row" }}>
        <View
          style={{
            flex: 1,
            flexDirection: "row",
            justifyContent: "center",
            alignContent: "center",
            alignItems: "center",
            textAlign: "justify"
          }}
        >
          <Card
            style={{
              padding: 10,
              elevation: 2,
              margin: 10,
              textAlign: "center",
              width: "95%",
              borderRadius: 20
            }}
            onPress={() => this.RBSheet.open()}
          >
            <Card.Content>
              <Image
                source={{
                  uri:
                    "http://guiadigital.madridactiva.anovagroup.es/" +
                    props.item.fotos[0]
                }}
                style={{
                  width: "100%",
                  height: 200,
                  padding: 5,
                  borderRadius: 10
                }}
                PlaceholderContent={<ActivityIndicator />}
              />

              <Text
                style={{
                  color: "#484855",
                  fontSize: RF(3.5),
                  paddingTop: 25,
                  textAlign: "center"
                }}
              >
                {props.item.nombre}
              </Text>

              <Text
                style={{
                  color: "#484855",
                  fontSize: RF(2),
                  paddingTop: 15,
                  textAlign: "center"
                }}
              >
                {props.item.descripcion.split(".")[0]}
              </Text>
            </Card.Content>
          </Card>
        </View>
      </View>
      <RBSheet
        ref={ref => {
          this.RBSheet = ref;
        }}
        animationType="slide"
        closeOnPressMask={true}
        height={RF(80)}
        duration={100}
        customStyles={{
          container: {
            justifyContent: "center",
            alignItems: "center",
            textAlign: "center",
            alignContent: "center",
            borderTopLeftRadius: 20,
            borderTopRightRadius: 20
          }
        }}
      >
        <Text
          style={{
            color: "#484855",
            fontSize: RF(3.5),
            paddingTop: 25,
            textAlign: "center"
          }}
        >
          {props.item.nombre}
        </Text>
      </RBSheet>
    </View>
  );
```

My Flatlist (Just in case)

```
<View
            style={{
              flex: 1,
              justifyContent: "center",
              textAlign: "center",
              alignItems: "center",
              marginTop: "5%"
            }}
          >
            <FlatList
              style={{
                width: "100%",
                alignContent: "center",
                backgroundColor: "#000"
              }}
              data={this.state.data}
              showsVerticalScrollIndicator={true}
              keyExtractor={item => item.nombre}
              renderItem={({ item }) => <Entry item={item} />}
            />
          </View>
```

I would like to be able to handle the data either in my custom component or in the flatlist screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already fix my issue, the problem was that the component wasn't declare as class so it doesn't keep props properly.

Once the component is declared and exported as class, every item in the flatlist is an object with its own props.

Answer (score 0):

With `shouldComponentUpdate` i think you should be able to control the datas inside the child component. See the react docs for more info https://it.reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate

Comment: I was reading the docs and check that usign React.PureComponent (As I'm using) shouldComponentUpdate is handle manually. 
I will check if using Component and shouldComponentUpdate works.